# JSON library for both Cocoa (Objective-C) and also Java

Tags: java, objective-c, json

Is there a JSON library that is good for use in both Cocoa Objective-C and also Java projects?

Comment: I believe Google (the company, not the search engine) has a JSON library as part of their Labs project, however I can't seem to find a link to it at the moment.

Comment: @Brian you're thinking of [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) but it's Java-only.

Comment: Java is a completely different beast from Objective-C. I've never heard of a library that can be directly used with both languages.

Comment: client side? ask doug crockford :)

Comment: why the heck do you need the same lib, the protocol (json) is what you use to transmit data between. after the parsing you should you local native to the system objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON library that's pretty much standard for Cocoa and Cocoa Touch projects is called JSON-framework and it's hosted on google code: http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

The JSON library for Java is called GSON, also from google code: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

I would recommend using both GSON and JSON frameworks (GSON for Java and JSON-Framework for objective-c).

Comment: I'm definitely a fan of GSON but it's hardly **the** JSON library for Java. There are many others.

Comment: Oh yah, I should have phrased that a little better. I recommend them both because of their similarities, in both libraries you call a single toJson or fromJson sort of function (objective-c it's JSONRepresentation) and using the language's reflection, it builds your json for you. This is just one of those mindset things, if both projects work similarly, it'll be easier to deal with.